# JSLink OnPostRender ist not called at ListView

Tags: list, list-view, jslink

I completely re-render my listviews via JSLink. To keep the original filter popup layout (and solve [this problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162559/js-link-and-csr-how-to-use-default-sorting-filtering-and-override-header)) I use the `onPostRender` handler to move the table headers around a little bit.
This is working very well.

**The problem is:** If I actually use the filter, SharePoint re-renders the List view without calling my `PostRender` function.

Can I trigger that elsewhere? Or is there a different event handler that I can use?

Comment: Is MDS enabled on that site?

Comment: Yes, I think so....

Answer (score 1):

If MDS is enabled on that site you will need to use `RegisterModuleInit()` to register your rendering script with the MDS engine so that it is consistently run.

To do that you will need to give a named entry point to your rendering script that you can use in `RegisterModuleInit()`.  So, your rendering script would have to change from:

```
(function() {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    // etc
    // etc
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

to

```
function myCustomRendering() {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    // etc
    // etc
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}

// register with MDS engine
// parameters are the URL/path of the script file, and the name of the function
RegisterModuleInit("/path/to/your/renderingScript.js", myCustomRendering);

// fallback for non-MDS sites, just call the function
myCustomRendering();
```

Here is a link to a [blog post that explains it further](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx).

Comment: I was wrong. A collegue of mine switched of MDS a couple of weeks ago. I haven't noticed. Sorry for that misleading information.

Answer (score 0):

Found a (quick 'n dirty) workaround:

Added the function by hand to my Templates.Body override:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {csListView.postRender();}, 50);
```

But I still hope that there's a better solution!